# Use of "first thing"

Tags: usage

Is it correct to say, "I did it first thing" instead of "I did it first"?

Comment: They're both "correct" in different contexts, but mean different things.

Answer (score 2):

The statement

> I did it first thing

means that you did it immediately upon arriving.

The statement

> I did it first

means that you did it before you did anything else or before anyone else.